# Error when trying to run our .net core project from wsl (works fine from windows)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, .net-core, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I try to run out asp.net core project (v6) directly from windows it works fine but if I try to run it from WSL(v2) I get this error:

`Configured debug type 'coreclr' is not supported.`

[image]

Here is our configuration

```
   {
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "GeminiLOB(mvc)",
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/${config:launchEnv}.env",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/GeminiLOB/Trs.Gemini.Web.GeminiLOB",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/GeminiLOB/Trs.Gemini.Web.GeminiLOB/bin/Debug/net6/Trs.Gemini.Web.GeminiLOB.dll",
      "launchSettingsProfile": "vscode",
      "sourceFileMap": {
        "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
      }
    },
```

The `install coreclr extension` don't seem to have anything to do with the issue. Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Are you running it from VSCode? Have you seen this Q&A: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2097

Answer (score 0):

So I got this piece figured out at least. Whatever Visual Studio code does to connect to a WSL2 instance it looks like you have to install all your extensions separately (workspaces).  I wasn't aware of this. Here is the C# extension

> This extension is disabled in this workspace because it is defined to
> run in Remote Extension Host. Please install this extension in
> 'WSL:fedora' to enable.
> [image]

Now that didn't fix everything. Still having issues of connecting to APIs ran in WSL2. Probably something to do with WSL2 network but i'll have to research that one later.